# Rspec test relating to upcase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm still new to rails and have a question for an assignment that I have relating to RSpec tests.

First, here are the assignment parameters:

1. Run before User is saved.
2. Split the users' name on a space (e.g. between a first name and a last  name). Loop over each name and uppercase the first letter. Re-combine the first and last names with a space in-between and save it to the name attribute.
3. Your solution does not have to check for an existing name that is properly formatted. For example, "Steve Jobs" is properly formatted, but your solution should work on it anyways.
4. Write your solution using TDD.

Here is what I came up with in my app/models/user.rb file:

`before_save { @name.map{|v| v.split.map{|x| x[0].upcase + name[1..-1]}.join(' ')}}`

This works for what I need it do do. I know I'm doing this backwards, but I'm a little unsure of how to write the RSpec test for this.

This is my attempt so far in spec/user_spec.rb:

`describe "capitalize user name" do
    it "should capitalize first and last names" do
      expect(name).to_be capitalize 
    end
  end`

Obviously this doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assignment like for school? (just trying to figure out if we should help or not)

Comment: We can help, @PhilipHallstrom, just note that "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it" ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). But judging by that test case, the user should read some RSpec tutorials before continuing... maybe he missed that class.

Comment: For example, it's hard to say what a good answer to this question would be. Write the tests for him?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your assignment parameters your test needs to create user, save it, then test to ensure that the name has been formatted correctly.  Something like:

```
it "should capitalize first and last names" do
  user = User.new(name: "jon malis")
  user.save!
  expect(user.name).to_eq "Jon Malis"
end
```

Some other things to think about... names like "Harry S. Truman" and "Madonna" and "Leonardo DiCaprio".  And lastly, go read about Ruby's `capitalize` method.

Comment: Thanks @Philip Hallstrom for pointing me in the right direction.